# Equations for walking forward

Tags: python, 3d, pygame

I wrote a simple 3D engine for pygame. Now I'm trying to create a simple first person controller for moving around a scene. The engine assumes a 3D grid with the player starting facing the negative z axis. The camera can rotate about the three axis as if it was at the origin. Currently the first person controller can only rotate around the y axis - i.e. look around 360 degrees. I'm trying to make the wasd controls move relative to which direction the camera is looking at.

Here is what I currently have (self.camera is a camera object from my 3D engine, which has the attributes x, y, z (position) and x_rot, y_rot, z_rot (rotation):

```
import python3d as p3d
import pygame
import math

class first_person_controller:
    def __init__(self,scene,camera,end_func):
        pygame.event.set_grab(True)
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        self.scene = scene
        self.camera = camera
        self.end_func = end_func

    def fps_control(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        relative = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
        self.camera.change_camera_rot([0,relative[0]/1000*-1,0])
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.camera.z += math.cos(self.camera.y_rot) * 5 * -1
            self.camera.x += math.sin(self.camera.y_rot) * 5 * -1
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.camera.z += math.cos(self.camera.y_rot) * 5
            self.camera.x += math.sin(self.camera.y_rot) * 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.camera.z += math.cos(self.camera.y_rot + math.radians(90)) * 5 * -1
            self.camera.x += math.sin(self.camera.y_rot + math.radians(90)) * 5 * -1
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.camera.z += math.cos(self.camera.y_rot + math.radians(90)) * 5
            self.camera.x += math.sin(self.camera.y_rot + math.radians(90)) * 5
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            self.end_func()
        if keys[pygame.K_c]:
            self.camera.y = 0
        elif not keys[pygame.K_c]:
            self.camera.y = 5
```

This is supposed to fit into a normal pygame loop like:

```
while True:
   clear screen
   fps_control()
   render scene
```

However, when implemented the first person controller goes off course, and at least appears to not walk in a straight line. I can't tell if this is because of my math, or my engine.

**If someone could tell me which is the issue - the trigonometry or the 3D engine, and if its the trigonometry suggest better equations, that would be great.**

If it helps, [here](https://github.com/MusicalHQ/python3D) is the 3D engine, but as of right now, the code isn't very readable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll probably be voted down for it, but whatever.

Your code reminds me a lot an earlier attempt to a 3D engine of my own. However, after facing numerous problem, I figured that Vectors would help me a LOT, and then I learned Matrices, as these helped **TONS MORE**.

And here is a link towards a course named [Vector Math for 3D computer graphics](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vectorindex.html) which is already great, but then you should even go a step further by using 4x4 Matrices. May seems like boring stuff, but you'll be glad to see how easy the logic becomes once you get it.